# Core Data - Discard changes

Tags: objective-c, core-data, model

Hope someone can explain what's going on.

If I get an object from my Core Data model, modify a property which is not persisted or even defined in the model! and then destroy and get the object again the value is still as previously set.

Why is this?

```
Promotion *promotion = [Promotion promotionWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1512] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [promotion setQuantity:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    NSLog(@"%d", [promotion.quantity intValue]);
    promotion = nil;

    promotion = [Promotion promotionWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1512] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSLog(@"%d", [promotion.quantity intValue]);
    promotion = nil;
```

Output is:

2
2

For information purposes:

```
+(Promotion *)promotionWithId:(NSNumber *)promotionId inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) context {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Promotion" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    NSPredicate *query = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"promotionId=%d", [promotionId intValue]];
    [fetchReq setPredicate:query];

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil]];

    if([resultArray count] > 0) {
        return [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Keep in mind that the changes you make to all managed objects are kept on Coredata's managed object context until you persist them (i.e. save the context).

So in your case, you are making a change to the managed object, setting it's reference to nil but not resetting the context.

This means your change is still valid and the next time you fetch the same object it will be applied.

To get rid of it completely, you will need to reset the context with:

```
[context reset];
```

From NSManagedObjectContext reset method documentation:

> All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this
>   method, you should ensure that you also discard references to any
>   managed objects fetched using the receiver, since they will be invalid
>   afterwards.

Comment: I have mark this as correct as it did send me in the right direction. Reset does just that. It resets the entire context which for me was a little overkill. For me rollback seemed a little more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Core Data caches objects, and the cache might retain the ivars that are not defined properties.

Try `[context refreshObject:promotion mergeChanges:NO]` then the log statement.

Comment: Thanks for replying and your suggestion makes perfect sense but unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: Hmm... even after working with Core Data for almost a year, sometimes I still don't quite understand. My only other thought is possible changing the retainsRegisteredObjects property. I am assuming the property isn't saved when you restart your app. I'll be interested to see the answer.

Comment: Correct if i restart the application without the setQuantity I get 0, 0. So no not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs in the code, and I have tried to explain what's going on on the RestKit mailing list. Let me just paste the answer here (with a few corrections to make the text easier to understand).

---

Naturally, the managed object context is not even aware of a property that is not defined in a model, and neither is the persistent object store. Hence, there must be something else.

Let's look at your code. You punched in `promotion = nil;` - which does not release the object. In that portion of the code, you don't have the leak, but the object is not released at that stage. That object is held by the resultArray.

So when does the object get released? It would be released along with `resultArray`. You are not freeing `resultArray` you allocated in `+promotionWithId:inManagedObjectContext:`. *You are not freeing it at all.* There also seems to be no reason to transform the result array into a mutable array in the first place.

Two variants of the solution:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil]];
[resultArray autorelease];
```

These are both autoreleased objects. If you go the autorelease route, the object would get released as soon as the nearest autorelease pool is drained or released. You can add your autorelease pool by wrapping the code in:
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
and
    [pool release];

Without this, the closest autorelease pool is probably in the Cocoa main run-loop. Thus, the `resultArray` (and hence your resulting object) would be released in the Cocoa main run-loop.

You may want to release `resultArray` directly inside `+promotionWithId:inManagedObjectContext:`, but not before retaining and autoreleasing `[resultArray objectAtIndex:0];`

So, what should happen when you release the object? It should, hopefully, be removed from the managed object context, and any fetched copy should then be a fault (since the original one is, or should be, gone). Frankly, I'm amazed that the same copy of the object is returned in the first place (and thanks for asking this question) -- but that is only logical, since Core Data is just an object graph manager which, conveniently, comes with a high-performance persistence layer.

You can also manually turn the object into a fault:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Hopefully this helps!