# Saving in child context saves to parent context automatically

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to create an update function that also allows the user to cancel the process.
I'm using the parent-child managedObjectContext and I've set the parent contest concurrency to NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. My plan was to not call the save for parent context to cancel the update.  When I tested my theory and commented out the said save lines, I found out the managedObject was still updated.  What am I doing wrong?

Partial update function code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[bgContext setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[bgContext setUndoManager:nil];

[bgContext performBlockAndWait:^{

    for (NSDictionary *itemDictionary in items) {
        //update cancelled
        if (status == -1) {
            return;
        }

        //Function to get a single managedObject by querying the main context.
        NSArray *array = [self queryEntity:entityName withResId:[dictionary objectForKey:@"res_id"]];

        //get the object id of queried managedobject; context -> mainContext
        ENTITY *object = (ENTITY *)[context objectWithID:[[array firstObject] objectID]];
        object.data = @"something"; //change data

        count++;

        //save every 100
        if(count%100 == 0) {
            [bgContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError *error;
                if(![bgContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"insert error child: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    //save excess
    if(count%100 != 0) {
        [bgContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error;
            if(![bgContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"insert error child: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }

    //comment out to prevent saving to parent
    /*[context performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"insert error parent: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];*/
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem. Thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825536/2260928 
I use these lines to ignore changes on cancel:

```
[bgContext reset];
[context reset];
```